# Using htaccess, how to restrict seeing directory contents, but allow server to use the contents?

Tags: php, .htaccess

More specifically, I have an htaccess file that restricts anyone from seeing the directory contents. Such that, nobody can see my 1000s of images in www.example.com/images by using:

```
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

However, I want to use these images on www.example.com such that, 
`<img src="images/thisimg.jpg" />` works.

I hope I'm in the right direction, but I appreciate any insight/re-direct. This is similar to: [How to protect all directory contents, but gain access to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390876/how-to-protect-all-directory-contents-but-gain-access-to-php-script) but I want to link to these images in that directory, and using `deny from all` does not allow me to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All you need to keep people from seeing the directory contents is an index.php or .html file in that folder.  Any requests for yoursite.com/images will load index.php, which you'll set to a dummy page.

index.html could be something like:

```
<html><title>Forbidden!</title><body>Nothing to see here...</body></html>
```

or a redirect script index.php:

```
<?php header('Location: /index.php'); exit(); ?>
```

Don't use .htaccess for blocking directory listings, it blocks access to everything.

Comment: This is incorrect, it should be done in htaccess.  For the same results you can override the ability to list in your apache/httpd config but neither will prevent a user from accessing an individual image.  Countless images and media have been accessed improperly on websites using this technique.  The user has to only guess the file name.

Comment: @Jason that's the thing... he doesn't want to block access to images.  He wants to link to the images on his pages and the users to be able to load them.  He just wanted to block the directory listing.

Comment: I see now and didn't totally understand his question.  My reaction to adding an index page to "secure" something is always Kill It With Fire.  However if your users need to be authenticated to see those images my answer still applies.  Thanks @Fosco

Comment: Well, I didn't mention I don't want these images to be used by anyone else either. I placed an htaccess to prevent hotlinking, but this does not prevent anyone from going into the source and finding the path of the image, then following that link to the image. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can check the referrer, implement some pass-thru hotlink detection script.. many things.  the .htaccess could come back, and you could use a .php file to read/output the images based on a parameter.

Comment: But the odds are no one is going to want your images, and if they do, it's probably a good thing.  When that happens, then you can worry about blocking it.  Don't get caught up in premature blocktimization.

Comment: Unfortunately, these images are digital goods and my client is concerned with these photos accessibility. Perhaps, I shouldn't be  storing these digital goods on the server? I appreciate your insight.

Comment: This might be a stupid comment, but say you have an images directory with a bunch of images in there that have a format like 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc., like avatars for a user profile or something like that.  The url for files in that directory is usually something like domain.com/image/xxx.xxx.  It is pretty easy to just sort of guess what filename might be and then just indirectly sort of browse the directory that way.  Is that not sort of security problem when it comes to having  photos of users stored on the filesystem ?, and is there a way around that besides using a BLOB, not recommended

Answer (score 53):

in .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.

Comment: Can you explain further please ? I 've see the link but can't figure out exactly what it mean...

Comment: This is wrong. what if domain has a sub page without file extension? eg: example.com/about-us (will return 404 error)

Comment: @HashanKanchana You are incorrect. You likely have something else set up wrong your .htaccess such as URL rewriting that is interfering with this line.

Answer (score 19):

### Option 1 (Easy but not Preferable)-

You do not need to create an **index** file like this-

```html
<html>
  <title>Forbidden!</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Access Denied !!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And place it in each resource directories and directories you don't want to show users.

### Option 2 (More Preferable)-

You can just add this at the end of your .htaccess file-

```
Options -Indexes
```

---

So, your **`.htaccess`** file may be like this-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

If you do that and try to go to a directory, you would get something like this-

[image]

---

So, no one will be able to discover any directory in server.

More can be found [**here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: I like this one because it's the best for user feedback. Forbidden!

Comment: It did'nt worked for me in .htaccess. Seems like .htaccess has no effect on my server.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution : create a blank page name `index.html` in your image folder :)

Comment: Is it a quick hack-what is the logic behind this?

Comment: @SIslam Yeah - index.html will be the page presented to the user, instead of a default list of the directory contents. If it's blank, the user will see nothing :)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this in .htaccess file:

```
 #
 ###################################################################
 ###                                                             ###
 ###                    Currently protection                     ###
 ###              images (jpg, jpeg, gif, png, bmp)              ###
 ###                       JavaScript (js)                       ###
 ###                Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)                 ###
 ###                                                             ###
 ###################################################################
 #
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ http://access-                    denied.us/hotlinks.html [NC,L]
 </ifModule>
 #
```

This will allow your pages to load the documents and images you want while stoping everyone elses pages from doing it.  I use this on all my sites and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

To me I feel the easiest way of getting it done is with a redirect. On the images directory, just create an index page and in the index page you have a redirect to your site index page i.e

```
<?php
   header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com' ) ;
?>
```

So that whenever anyone tries to access the image page directly they end up going to your site's root.

Answer (score 1):

`deny from all` allows files to be used by server side scripts but restricts complete web access.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd just make sure that the referrer is www.example.com, that's kinda one of it's main uses.

Comment: You can spoof the referrer though, so someone will eventually figure that loophole out.

Answer (score 0):

Magicianeer's suggestion is the best for this problem. If your images are broken into subfolders you'd have to put an index file in each one. 'Options -Indexes' only needs to be done once at the root.

Comment: deny from all alows files to be used by server side scripts but restricts complete web access.

Answer (score 0):

in that folder which you want to show access forbidden 
create a file with name index.php and paste this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access This Folder
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick which makes people think they've accessed a folder which doesn't exist.

### Create a HTML file and add this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And, how would we load this page once the folder that "doesn't exist" is accessed by the user? I'm not sure your answer is very clear.